# How can I programmatically redefine a Pivot Table datasource in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Using 'CopyFromRecordset' has been an effective way to keep a data source from MS Access to a pivot table- 'unlinked'.

The Access database produces the report which is independent and can be e-mailed with no macros.

I'm trying to write a routine that will automatically redefine the  datasource for the pivot table.  I know enough to clean up a recorded macro, so that it doesn't have stray Excel objects left open, but sometimes I miss something that either leaves an object open - OR doesn't set the object right.

In this particular case, it is on this line:

```
xlSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, xlSheet.Range(rngWorkingRange), , xlYes).Name _
        = "tbl_MOSI"
```

I get Run-time error '1004'
Object defined error

Here is my complete routine for reference:

```
Public Sub GetMOSIData(strSheetToPlaceData As String, strPathToWorkbook As String)

'Puts a recordset into a specific cell of an Excel workbook 


'''
'8 objects created
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim WB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim xlMain As Object
Dim xlOther As Object
Dim fld As Variant
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rngWorkingRange As Range


Dim x As Integer


'''
'6 objects set
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPathToWorkbook)

Set xlSheet = WB.Sheets(strSheetToPlaceData) 'or you can manually type the sheet name in place of strSheetToPlaceData
Set xlMain = WB.Sheets("MOSI")
Set xlOther = WB.Sheets("SKL-LV-View")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from " & strSheetToPlaceData)

'Assumes you will use A1 as the anchor cell - but it can be changed

'FIRST CLEAR THE RANGE OF CELLS
xlSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

'PLACE THE FIELD NAMES
x = 1
For Each fld In rs.Fields
    xlSheet.Cells(1, x).Value = fld.Name
    x = x + 1
Next

'PLACE
xlSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

'determine the data range for the PivotTable


'RECORDING FOR REFERENCE - I DON'T USE THIS CODE
'
'    Sheets("tbl_MOSI_Detail").Select
'    Range("C4").Select
'    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$AB$23411"), , xlYes).Name _
'        = "Table1"
'    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
'    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
'    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Name = "tbl_MOSI"
'    Sheets("MOSI").Select
'    Range("G4").Select
'    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvMOSI").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches. _
'        Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="tbl_MOSI_Detail!tbl_MOSI", _
'        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
'END RECORDING FOR REFERENCE

'ATTEMPT to clean up recording...
'7th object set
Set rngWorkingRange = xlSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'convert tbl_MOSI_Detail Range into a Table

    xlSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, xlSheet.Range(rngWorkingRange), , xlYes).Name _
        = "tbl_MOSI"
    xlSheet.ListObjects("tbl_MOSI").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

'set pvMOSI to point to this table
    xlMain.PivotTables("pvMOSI").ChangePivotCache WB.PivotCaches. _
        Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="tbl_MOSI_Detail!tbl_MOSI", _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)

xlMain.RefreshAll
xlMain.Select

WB.Save
WB.Close

xlApp.Quit

'8 objects destroyed
Set rs = Nothing
Set rngWorkingRange = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlMain = Nothing
Set xlOther = Nothing
Set WB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing


PresentExcel (strPathToWorkbook)
MsgBox "MOSI report is complete", vbOKOnly, "MOSI"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rngWorkingRange` variable is a Range and you're using it like a String.  You need

```
xlSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngWorkingRange, , xlYes).Name _
    = "tbl_MOSI"
```

You could have also said `xlSheet.Range(rngWorkingRange.Address)`, but that would just be silly.

What you did say, is `xlSheet.Range(rngWorkingRange.Value)` because Value is the default property of a Range object. If rngWorkingRange was a single cell whose value could be interpreted as a range address, you would not have got an error. But rngWorkingRange.Value returns an array and xlSheet.Range(...) doesn't know what to do with an array.

Comment: Excellent.  If it was a snake, it would've bit me.  Thanks!